# Can a Quotient of a Group by Two Different Subgroups be Isomorphic?

Tags: gr.group-theory

If I have a group $G$ with two two subgroups $H$ and $I$ such that $G/H \approx G/I$, what can I say about the relationship between $H$ and $I$? Are they equal; isomorphic?

Sorry if this question is below the level of the site.

Comment: They don't have to be equal or even isomorphic.  (Z/6 x Z/4)/(3Z/6 x 2Z/4) is isomorphic to (Z/6 x Z/4)/(0 x Z/4).

Comment: I have heard that "Ask An Algebraist" is a good place for questions like this:  http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_an_algebraist;task=list

Comment: Suppose I have two groups $G,H$ and two surjective group homomorphisms $l,m:G \to H$. Will there be some type of equivalence between ker$(l)$ and ker$(m)$?

Comment: No, that is a reformulation of the same question.  See Mariano's interesting example below; one of the kernels can be trivial while the other isn't, so in particular they don't even have to have the same cardinality.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There exists groups $G$ with normal proper non-trivial subgroups $H$ such that $G \cong G/H$. Even finitely presented ones, as the one given by [Higman, Graham. A finitely related group with an isomorphic proper factor group. J. London Math. Soc.  26,  (1951). 59--61. [MR0038347](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0038347)], namely the group $G$ freely generated by $a$, $b$ and $c$ subject to $$a^{-1}ca=b^{-1}cb=c^2,$$ with $H$ normally generated by adding the relation $$aca^{-1}=bcb^{-1}.$$

Comment: That's a little unsettling.

Comment: By the way, the paper is a pleasure to read!

Comment: A group with a self-epimorphism with non-trivial kernel is called non-Hopfian.  Another nice example is (2,3)-Baumslag--Solitar group, generated by a and b, in which b, with the relation which asserts that b conjugates a^2 to a^3.

Comment: A simpler example is an infinite dimensional vector space under addition, e.g., $\mathbb R^\mathbb N$. It's the finitely generated part which is odd. 

Comment: @Douglas, there was a previous example known which was finitely generated but without finite presentation. Higman's group adds finite presentation to the game, as well as the charm of its simplicity :P

Comment: Yes, but my point is that there are much more familiar examples which obviously exhibit the same behavior. C4 x C2 has nonisomorhpic subgroups of size 4 which have isomorphic quotients, and any infinitely generated free abelian group has quotients isomorphic to itself by the definition of infinite. I like the Baumslag-Solitar groups and have proved theorems about them, but they are not that simple to most people who would ask this question. 

Comment: @Mariano: Let $G = \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}_{i}$. $H= \mathbb{Z} \times \{0\} \times \{0\} \cdots$. Then $G \cong G/H$.